# POST a http form and get the target html using web scraping

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am currently working on building a site to post to third party site and pull details from them using the below approach

```
String htmlCode = "<html>" +
"<head>" +
"<title>Form</title>" +
"</head>" +
"<body onload=\"javascript:document.forms[0].submit()>" +
"<form method=\"post\" action=\"%verylongactionurl%\">" +
"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key\" value=\"value\">" +
"</form>" +
"</body>" +
"</html>";
```

I replace all the required values in the above html string in my c# code and then am doing the below to write the content on to my page which is working perfectly fine

```
Response.Write(httpForm);
```

Is there a way that I can capture the target form's html that I get in the above step in my code?

This is for a new requirement to do a web scraping and pull the required details from the target site and display the required values in our application.

I tried the below code which is not working. I am seeing a error page of target site in the reponseURL which I get back.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sourceUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
string postData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String.Format("key={0}&", value));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

// This is sent to the Post
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


//request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, postData.Length);
    requestStream.Flush();
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Maybe there's a different HTTP status than expected in the response that might be a clue in itself?

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```js
//Createing instans of web client
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

//Getting the html content of the whattsap application page for android
string HtmlString = wc.DownloadString("http://www.whatsapp.com/android");

//Loading the html content into HtmlAgilityPack HTML Document
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(HtmlString);

//Extracting The latest version string from the HTML content by searching the "P" with class named version
//and retriving it's inner text.
_currentVersion = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("version")).First().InnerText;

//removing the "Version" keyword from the version string so we can get only rhe version number
_currentVersion = _currentVersion.Replace("Version", "").Trim();
```

in this example i'm Extracting the latest version number of whatsapp application
strait from there web site.

so the only thing you have to post is the web url you need to extract data from